# Application_Error System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect Value cannot be null

Tags: c#, url, exception, null, response.redirect

I am getting an error with only a few users when they click my submit button on my form
the following is the exception...

> Exception occured in: System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect Message: Value
>   cannot be null. Parameter name: url Source: System.Web Stack Trace: at
>   System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse,
>   Boolean permanent)
>   The users hits the subit I then call a webservice which returns a documentID and then I redirect the  user to the external site to begin the document..

here is my code I am checking the URL to make sure it has one

```
//If the document was successfully created then the user will be redirected to assure sign to immediately sign the document.
                if (isSuccessfull)
                {
                    //Re Directing the user to immediately sign the document.  In assure sign it is called immediate presentment.
                    //ToDo: When testing change the ProductionBaseUrl to the SandBoxBaseURL
                    var redirectUrl =
                        documentNowSubmit.BuildDocuementSigningUrl(
                            ApplicationSettingsFactory.GetApplicationSettings().ProductionBaseUrl, ui_txtEmailAddress.Text,
                            documentResult[0].Id.ToString(),
                            documentResult[0].AuthToken.ToString(),
                            signatoryListQueryResult, string.Empty);
                    if (redirectUrl != string.Empty)
                    {
                        Response.Redirect(redirectUrl, false); //02/14/2013 Removed the end response true from the redirect.
                        //HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); //Added the complete request call..
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentNullException("redirectUrl", "User" + fullName  + "-" + emailAddress + ": Document signing url is empty.");
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    var additionalInformation = "User name: " + userName + " Document Title: " + documentTitle +
                                                " Template Id: " +
                                                templateId;
                    throw new Exception(
                        "An error has occurred with the submission of your document. With the following additional information: " +
                        additionalInformation + " Please contact the service desk for additional help. " +


  assureSignExceptionMsgs);
                }
```

I have the error catching in the global.asax in the Application_Error

it is always getting into the LogAndClearException

```
   //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // NAME: Application_Error
        // CHANGE LOG:
        // Date              Programmer          Description
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------

        //If the last error or associated base exception do not have value, exit immediately.
        if (Server.GetLastError() == null)
        {
            return;
        }


        //Ignore 'A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll'
        //This happens and is documented by Microsoft because the Server.End() is being called. This can happen when an unauthenticated user tries 
        //to access this site and the Response.Resirect is called or if a Response.Redirect is within a Try-Catch block.
        if (Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException() is System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
        {
            Server.ClearError();
            return;
        }

        //Log the exception in addition to redirecting to the error page
        LogAndClearException();
    }
```

Cant figure out why some users are getitng the error and some are not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend checking redirectUrl by using `string.IsNullOrEmpty(..)` **instead of comparing to string.Empty.**

I would assume

```
  var redirectUrl = documentNowSubmit.BuildDocuementSigningUrl(..)
```

returns null in some cases!

Answer (score 0):

It was when I did a string compare I forgot to add toLower to my strings to make sure they were both the same case.  I also added the above.